# How to merge 2 branch in XCode?

Tags: xcode, git, github, merge

We are two developer and we want to work on a same project at the same time. So, we use GitHub. However, we couldn't do this.

This is our problem;

I am pushing new xcode project to our master, then, my friend are pulling this xcode project. Every thing is ok since here. Then, I am changing some codes, then, I am pushing (commit and push) it again. When my friend change some codes (he didn't pull) and push it, there is an error like this: "The local repository is out of date. Make sure all changes have been pulled from the remote repository and try again."

Actually, we want that, we change some come codes, then, I and my friend push it, then these two file will be merged. How can we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he will need to do `git pull --rebase` which will pull the branch and put his changes on top of yours

you should really branch each feature though and work on the conflicts during merge

Comment: Assuming your command to get that error was just `git pull` then yes